# Different definitions of Riemann tensor components

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, definition, conventions, curvature

Hobson (*General Relativity* 2006 ed. page 158 eq. 7.13) and Ryder (*Introduction to General Relativity* 2009 ed. page 124 eq. 4.31) define Riemann tensor components as
$$ {R^\alpha}_{\beta\gamma\delta} = \partial_\gamma {\Gamma^\alpha}_{\beta\delta} - \partial_\delta {\Gamma^\alpha}_{\beta\gamma} + {\Gamma^\alpha}_{\epsilon\gamma} {\Gamma^\epsilon}_{\beta\delta} - {\Gamma^\alpha}_{\epsilon\delta} {\Gamma^\epsilon}_{\beta\gamma} $$
while Weinberg (*Gravitation and Cosmology* 1972 ed. page 133 eq. 6.1.5) defines
$$ - {R^\alpha}_{\beta\gamma\delta} = \partial_\gamma {\Gamma^\alpha}_{\beta\delta} - \partial_\delta {\Gamma^\alpha}_{\beta\gamma} - {\Gamma^\alpha}_{\epsilon\gamma} {\Gamma^\epsilon}_{\beta\delta} + {\Gamma^\alpha}_{\epsilon\delta} {\Gamma^\epsilon}_{\beta\gamma} $$
Notice the last two terms sign changes completely so the two definitions seem incompatible: why these two different definitions?

Comment: I believe Gravitation, by Misner and Thorne, has a table summarizing various sign conventions used in general relativity text books. Welcome to the nightmare world of non-standardized conventions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different conventions for the *signature* (number of positive, negative and zero eigenvalues counted with multiplicity for a symmetric square matrix, according to [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia), those values are independent of the basis used) of the Minkowski metric, called the *west coast* and *east coast convention* with signature $(1,3,0)$ and $(3,1,0)$ respectivly:
$$\eta_{\mu\nu}=\operatorname{diag}(+1,-1,-1,-1)$$
$$\eta_{\mu\nu}=\operatorname{diag}(-1,+1,+1,+1)$$
The first one was used by Richard Feynman (living at the West Coast of the US), while the second one was used by Julian Schwinger (living at the East Coast of the US). (By the way, they probably had one or another heated discussion about the conventions as they got a Nobel Prize together.) There are many reasons for the existence of both convetions, one convention is better for doing special or general relativity while he other is better for doing quantum field theory.

All of this effects in particular general relativity: Note, that when you change the sign of the metric tensor (as well as its inverse indirectly) the sign in front of the Christoffel symbol:
$$\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\sigma
=\frac{1}{2}g^{\sigma\kappa}\left(\partial_\mu g_{\kappa\nu}+\partial_\nu g_{\kappa\mu}-\partial_\kappa g_{\mu\nu}\right)$$
won't change and therefore the entire Riemann tensor won't as well. Therefore I assume, that when you change the convention, you also change the minus sign in the definition of the Christoffel symbol, which would explain, why the first two terms in the Riemann curvature tensor (with an odd number of them) are affected while the last two terms (with an even number of them) aren't.

Different definitions making all of this worse are for example done for the Ricci tensor (contraction of the Riemann curvature tensor), but the two different definitions $R_{\mu\nu}=R_{\mu\sigma\nu}^\sigma$ and $R_{\mu\nu}=R_{\mu\nu\sigma}^\sigma$ again differ my a minus sign due to the algebraic symmetries of the Riemann curvature tensor.

A little overview about this chaos is also given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_convention).

Comment: Very clear, thank you. So, despite the different convention, the main reason is that Christoffel symbol is defined with opposite signs in the two conventions?

Comment: You're welcome! I don't know the formulas for both conventions, but after thinking about it for half an hour (my answer first wrongly attributed the sign change of the to the partial derivative, after posting I noticed that it also appears in the Christoffel symbol), I can't think of any other explanation than the sign change already appearing in the definition. I have not yet seen this explicitly done for the Christoffel symbol, but I definitly know it is sometimes done when dealing with the different conventions. Usually, this only makes it worse, so I would not think too much about it.